# Outputting line numbers

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way, in VB.NET, to output the current line number in the source code? For example:

```
Try
    ' The following line will purposly cause an error
    Dim BigNum As Int64
    Dim LittleNum As Int16 = CShort(BigNum)
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim LineNumber As Integer = <linenumber> ' How do I do this?
    MessageBox.Show("Error in source code. Line: " + LineNumber)
End Try
```

Is there any way to fill the LineNumber variable in the example above with the actual line number in the source code that caused the error?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job:

```
Dim stackTrace = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex)
Dim stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 1)
Dim lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber()
```

Note that `GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 1))` gets the *first* frame pushed onto the stack. In this case, this is the frame containing the current try-catch block, which is what you want. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe.aspx) for more info.)

Comment: Glad to help. Unless you have any further queries, would you mind accepting it as answer?

Comment: I tried it out, but the StackFrame contains no information (GetFileName returns Nothing and GetFileLineNumber returns 0). Did I miss something?

Comment: @Fredrik: It definitely works. You must however be running in debug mode with symbols loaded - insure that that is the case.

Comment: Running debug with symbols loaded; it surprised me that I didn't get it to work since this was the solution that immediately came to my mind as well. Probably some issue with my environment though, I would suspect, I trust your solution to work.

Comment: @Fredrik: Yeah, that sounds quite unusual. Indeed it is probably some issue specific to your environment.

Comment: This is pretty awesome. But is there any way to log the line number for logging purposes if you don't have an exception?

Comment: @alord1689: Absolutely. The code is almost identical, except you use the parameterless constructor of `StackTrace`. (This gets the stack trace for the current point in execution.)

Answer (score 0):

The line number will be in the Exception's stack trace already. I think it even shows in a simple ex.ToString.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to correct Noldorin's response because s/he used the wrong Stacktrace constructor:

```
Dim stackTrace = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, True)
Dim stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 1)
Dim lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber()
```

Specifying `True` as the second argument for the constructor tells it to capture the stack source information at the time of creation. Without it `stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber()` will always return 0.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx for an explanation of the correct constructor and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25h0kw08.aspx to show the constructor that Noldorin suggested. Note the remarks section which states:

> The StackTrace is created with the caller's current thread, and does
>   not contain file name, line number, or column information.
>
> The resulting stack trace describes the stack at the time of the
>   exception.